# CSS to remove “comments count” icon from main page

Tags: customization, css, homepage, icon

as the title suggests, can you help me on how to remove icons on the homepage that show the comment count of each article?
I do not know CSS, and I do not know exactly what to change. I am using the following theme: https://demo.codevibrant.com/gaming-mag/ and I want to remove all the zeros in red.

Thanks for any answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add "display:none;" to specific CSS class.

add

```
span.comments-link a {
        display: none;
    }
```

Comment: I added that line of code into Appearance => Customize => Additional CSS but not work

Comment: what is the url of your site ? on demo, it works well !

Comment: https://www.elitedangerousitalia.it/

Comment: are you still there?

Comment: i updated the answear with something more powerfull that hide it everywhere.

Comment: if this fits to you, don't hesitate to validate my answear !